# IOS 5 How to change the color of back button in a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, back-button

I want to change the color of back button of a navigation bar to make it look like this[image]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Set the `backBarButtonItem`'s `tintColor`:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

**TIP**: If you want this to be applied to *all* `UIBarButtonItem` instances in your application by default, then you can use the new [`UIAppearance`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) API to do just that:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: I tried this- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    UIImageView *image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logobar.png"]];
    
    NSLog(@"Frame==%f",image.frame.size.width);
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.navigationItem.titleView= image; 
    NSLog(@"%f",self.navigationItem.titleView.frame.size.width);
   


}
but it is not working

Comment: [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; This method is present for IOS 5.0 or above how to make it work for lower versions?

Comment: @NileshTupe You will need to use the other line of code that I've provided, which should work in the context of the pushed view controller.

Comment: I have put that code in viewdidload method of pushed view controller.But it has no effect.Where should I put that line ?

Comment: You shouldn't put the first line in viewDidLoad of the pushed view controller. You should put it in viewDidLoad of the PUSHING view controller, and all controllers pushed from it will have the correct back button.

Answer (score 8):

The first line of jacob's answer didn't work for me because the backBarButtonItem was NULL. It is NULL because it's been created later automatically when switching to an other ViewController. At that time you can set the title of the button with

```
self.title = @"nice title"; // self is here the view(controller) within the popoverController
```

but you can't set the tintColor.

What worked for me, was to create a new UIBarButtonItem without any style. Then set the title and color propertys and set it as backBarButtonItem.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
backButton.title = @"go back - now!";
backButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.5 blue:0.7 alpha:1.0];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[okButton release];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make the button look exactly like in your picture, you may use an image, too:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_bg"]
                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The background image must be a resizable image for good results.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found to set it globally or locally is

```
    [[UIBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
         [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
         [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
         [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:0.0], UITextAttributeFont, 
      nil] 
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

try this It is working for me...