# How to change Default navigation item color

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have an Navigation bar and I want to change its left item  default color to White.

[image]

I WANT THE BLUE TO BE WHITE

I want to done this programmatically.
 Currently i am using this code to change the color and title of navigation bar

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
self.navigationItem.title = @"Advanced Settings";
UIColor *bg = [UIColor colorWithRed:79/255.0f green:166/255.0f blue:196/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    // iOS 6.1 or earlier
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = bg;
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};

} else {
    // iOS 7.0 or later
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = bg;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]};
}
 }
```

Comment: self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; just put the line in ViewDidLoad method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 7 UIBarButton back button arrow color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384488/ios-7-uibarbutton-back-button-arrow-color)

Comment: There are at least three questions with answers to this: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384488/ios-7-uibarbutton-back-button-arrow-color , 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929382/ios-5-how-to-change-the-color-of-back-button-in-a-navigation-bar 3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029833/ios-7-navigation-bar-text-and-arrow-color you should really consider searching before posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below line of code

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = bg;//you are setting for entire navigation bar
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];//setting the buttons tint color
```

Hope it helps you...!

Answer (score 4):

Use this code in AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // set Navigation button color
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope following code would be helpful to you

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   [[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```